# Django class based signup view form not show up in bootstrap modal

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, bootstrap-5

I try to look up my signup view as a bootstrap modal but when click form doesn't show

```
class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    template_name = 'avapp/signup.html'
    success_message = 'Success: Sign up succeeded. You can now Log in.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

views.py

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}

    <h1 style="text-align: center;color: #568203 " > Avakado App</h1>
    <center>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-success" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal    " >
            <img style="text-align: center" src="{% static '1_org.jpg' %}" width="300" height="450" >
        </a>
    </center>
    
{% endblock  %}
```

index.html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <form action="/signup" method="POST">
        <div class="modal-body">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        </div>
        </form>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

signup.html

[this is the modal form looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyACg.png)

Can I figure it out without using Ajax or something else or do I have to change my signup view from class based views to something else

Comment: do not share code images. only share in code format

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.